# How should I connect SVGs using canvas in responsive environment using HTML5?

Tags: css, html, jsp, svg, responsive-design

I have 2 SVG rectangles connected by one canvas. I tried HTML5 to make it responsive. SVG is reacting to the code, but the canvas is static, so the connection between them is lost. What can i do?

Comment: Can you provide your code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an svg element as a ViewBox.
e.g.:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1">             
        <rect width="0.4" height="0.3" y="0" x="0" fill="yellow"/>
        <rect width="0.2" height="0.2" y="0" x="0" fill="blue"/>            
</svg>
```

Comment: i used viewbox for svg. what about the canvas? it is staying static and not changing with svgs

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg style="position:relative; top: 20x; left: -4px;width: 200; height: 175">
  <rect x="5" y="2" rx="20" ry="20" width="100" height="150" style="fill:#FF7070;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5">
  </rect>
</svg>

<svg style="position:absolute; top: 80px; left: 430px">
  <rect x="5" y="2" rx="20" ry="20" width="200" height="100" style="fill:#FF7070;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5">
  </rect>
</svg>

<canvas id="canvas1" style=" background-color : gray; position: absolute;top:112px; 
left: 110px ;x-index:1;" width="323" height="7" `enter code here`>
</canvas>
```

Comment: is viewBox responsive in phone and tablets?